# Jquery Sortable, delete current Item by drag out

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

My Problem:
The sortable event out: fires when I drag something in the list or when I sort the list.
But I only want to start the function when I drag an item out.

My code

```
        $(document).ready(function ust()
        {    
            $('#div1').sortable({
                out: function(event, ui) { $('#nfo').append('OUT<br />'); }
            });

        });
```

Working example
http://jsfiddle.net/FrbW8/22/

Comment: Hmm, is this a Jquery Bug? Coz ...
Out -> This event is triggered when a sortable item is moved away from a connected list.
Start -> This event is triggered when sorting starts.
Stop -> This event is triggered when sorting has stopped.

Comment: Blair - That's just about the stupidest excuse I've seen so far on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the out callback. See this jquery ui [trac ticket](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/3988)

I really do not agree with the 'logical' behaviour notion.

> "However, note that the "out" callback
>   will still be triggered if you drag
>   into a list and then release the mouse
>   (but not if you're not over the list).
>   This is logical behaviour and happens
>   for normal sortables as well."

Comment: is it possible to stop the fire? For example, i add sortstart and sortstop. -> If sortart: -> abbort out: ... if sortstop: -> abbort out:

Comment: That will get messy I think. You could try need to get your hands dirty and change the jquery ui src to stop this 'out' behaviour.

Comment: Hey redsquare,
but when i change the src,  i must change it after every ui update. :(
Right?

Comment: @Peter yes, that is the downside - unless you submit a ticket with the change if you believe it is wrong and they include it in the next release

Comment: And there is no other way? For exmaple: destroy sortable -> make dragable? ... Jquery is a little bit new 4 me, so i dont know every possible approach. :(

Answer (score 38):

Use beforeStop to intercept the item and remove it:

```
receive: function(e, ui) { sortableIn = 1; },
over: function(e, ui) { sortableIn = 1; },
out: function(e, ui) { sortableIn = 0; },
beforeStop: function(e, ui) {
   if (sortableIn == 0) { 
      ui.item.remove(); 
   } 
}
```

(I originally found this in the Google, but can no longer find the link. So, I apologize for not referencing the source.)

Comment: It looks like this prevents normal sorting of the items. If I use this and drag the items to sort, even if it never moves out of the control, if removes the item.

Comment: Works pretty well. I instead use hasClass to check if it was out because I was adding the class in the out function to indicate to the user that the item was out of an area.

Answer (score 5):

The other solutions doesn't seems to work with connected sortable lists so I'm posting my own solution that works perfectly for my case. This makes use of the "droppable" plugin capturing the "drop" event when the elements are dropped outside of the sortable lists.

```
$('#div1').sortable({
    ....
}).droppable({greedy: true})

$('body').droppable({
    drop: function ( event, ui ) {          
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of this approach in action: http://jsfiddle.net/n3pjL/

Comment: That's an approach I tried today unsuccessfully, because I didn't find the `greedy` option. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I use `this.element.find('.ui-sortable-helper').length` to make difference between "sort out event" and "drop out event". When you are sorting, sorted item has class ui-sortable-helper. After drop there is no other ui-sortable-class until you start sorting again (at least in my script). Hope to help someone.